# How to Update iCal with Command Line

Tags: mac, command-line, terminal, calendar.app

Anyone knows of a way to update/view/edit iCal events using Terminal command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applescript should do the trick - see http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/vol.21/21.11/scriptingical/index.html

Comment: Thanks. I meant more like a live command-line, less automatic script, but a way to use Terminal like so: "ical add 12/12/09 13:45 Visit Mom"

Comment: You can call an Applescript from the terminal and pass arguments to it - see http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html for an example.

Comment: This answer is out of date!